# Solve terrible performance after upgrading from Lucene 4.0 to 4.1

Tags: java, lucene

After upgrading from Lucene 4.0 to 4.1 my solution's performance degraded by more than an order of magnitude. The immediate cause is the unconditional compression of stored fields. For now I'm reverting to 4.0, but this is clearly not the way forward; I'm hoping to find a different approach to my solution.

I use Lucene as a database index, meaning my stored fields are quite short: just a few words at most.

I use a `CustomScoreQuery` where in `CustomScoreProvider#customScore` I end up loading all candidate documents and perform detailed word-similarity scoring against the query. I employed two levels of heuristic to narrow down the candidate document set (based on [Dice's coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dice%27s_coefficient)), but in the last step I need to match up each query word against each document word (they could be in different order) and calculate the total score based on the sum of best word matches.

How could I approach this differently and do my calculation in a way that avoids the pitfall of loading compressed fields during query evaluation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Lucene 3.x I had this:

```
new CustomScoreQuery(bigramQuery, new FieldScoreQuery("bigram-count", Type.BYTE)) {
  protected CustomScoreProvider getCustomScoreProvider(IndexReader ir) {
    return new CustomScoreProvider(ir) {
      public double customScore(int docnum, float bigramFreq, float docBigramCount) {
         ... calculate Dice's coefficient using bigramFreq and docBigramCount...
         if (diceCoeff >= threshold) {
           String[] stems = ir.document(docnum).getValues("stems");
           ... calculate document similarity score using stems ...
         }
      }
    };
  }
}
```

This approach allowed efficient retrieval of cached `float` values from stored fields, which I used to get the bigram count of a document; it didn't allow retrieving strings, so I needed to load the document to get what I need to calculate document similarity score. It worked okayish until the Lucene 4.1 change to compress stored fields.

The proper way to leverage the enhancements in Lucene 4 is to involve `DocValues` like this:

```
new CustomScoreQuery(bigramQuery) {
  protected CustomScoreProvider getCustomScoreProvider(ReaderContext rc) {
    final AtomicReader ir = ((AtomicReaderContext)rc).reader();
    final ValueSource 
       bgCountSrc = ir.docValues("bigram-count").getSource(),
       stemSrc = ir.docValues("stems").getSource();
    return new CustomScoreProvider(rc) {
      public float customScore(int docnum, float bgFreq, float... fScores) {
        final long bgCount = bgCountSrc.getInt(docnum);
        ... calculate Dice's coefficient using bgFreq and bgCount ...
        if (diceCoeff >= threshold) {
          final String stems = 
             stemSrc.getBytes(docnum, new BytesRef())).utf8ToString();
          ... calculate document similarity score using stems ...
        }
      }
    };
  }
}
```

This resulted in a performance improvement from 16 ms (Lucene 3.x) to 10 ms (Lucene 4.x).

Answer (score 2):

In the [`IndexWriterConfig`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriterConfig.html), you can pass in a [`Codec`](https://builds.apache.org/job/Lucene-Artifacts-trunk/javadoc/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriterConfig.html#setCodec%28org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec%29), which defined the storage method to be used by the index.  This will only take effect when the `IndexWriter` is constructed (that is, changing the config after construction will have no effect).  You'll want to use [`Lucene40Codec`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene40/package-summary.html).

Something like:

```
//You could also simply pass in Version.LUCENE_40 here, and not worry about the Codec
//(though that will likely affect other things as well)
IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_41, analyzer);
config.setCodec(new Lucene40Codec());
IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(directory, config);
```

You could also use [`Lucene40StoredFieldsFormat`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene40/Lucene40StoredFieldsFormat.html) directly to get the old, uncompressed stored field format, and pass it back from a custom Codec implementation.  You could probably take most of the code from [`Lucene41Codec`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene41/Lucene41Codec.html), and just replace the `storedFieldFormat()` method.  Might be the more targeted approach, but a touch more complex, and I don't know for sure whether you might run into other issues.

A further note on creating a custom codec, the way the API indicates that you should accomplish this is to extend FilterCodec, and modifying their example a bit to fit:

public final class CustomCodec extends FilterCodec {

```
 public CustomCodec() {
   super("CustomCodec", new Lucene41Codec());
 }

 public StoredFieldsFormat storedFieldsFormat() {
   return new Lucene40StoredFieldsFormat();
 }
```

}

---

Of course, the other implementation that springs to mind:

I think it's clear to you, as well, that the the issue is right around "I end up loading all candidate documents".  I won't editorialize too much on a scoring implementation I don't have complete details on or understanding of, but it sounds like your fighting against Lucene's architecture to make it do what you want.  Stored fields shouldn't be used for scoring, generally, and you can expect performance to suffer very noticeably as a result using the 4.0 stored field format, as well, though to a somewhat lesser extent.  Might there be a better implementation, either in terms of scoring algorithm, or in terms of document structure, that will remove the requirement to score documents based on stored fields?

Comment: I tried the `Lucene40Codec` first, but, as its Javadoc claims, it's read-only. Now I'm writing a custom codec, but my issue is that I'm on Clojure so it's not as straightforward. On your last point, that's really my main question: how could I get the scoring I need in a way that plays along with the idea of index lookup. I have already spent many days and sleepless nights trying to come up with something better for 3.6, no luck. My hope is that there may be something new in 4 that I may use.

Comment: I can't really answer well on how to modify your logic to use indexed fields rather than stored fields.  I don't have a clear understanding of what you are trying to accomplish with that.  The last step you indicated seems to be the problem, I assume, where you match up each query word against each document word, but what is this meant to accomplish?

Comment: In specific terms, I match entered street name to the street names database. I need to ignore word order and even missing words (e.g. street named after a person is mostly called just be the surname, but the full street name contains the first name as well); on the other hand, I must know **all** words in the "document" (street name) to produce the total score.

Comment: You case of searching with only a subset of the words present in a field is typical to the point of being assumed.  The question is, why do you need to know all the terms?  There isn't a performant way to get everything **stored** with the document.  Can you give me some idea of what is inadequate about Lucene's typical scoring scheme?

Comment: Actually, it's not just a subset; there is a small penalty against missing words (it was only through testing that I determined that the penalty should be that small). Note also that this is symmetrical: the words may be missing at either end. Next, I have no idea in advance **which** terms in a doc I should match because it's all based on `JaroWinklerDistance`. There is nothing **right** about  Lucene's scoring: I don't need either TF or IDF factored in. I have a custom `Similarity` that fixes these to unity.

Comment: I don't believe with a JaroWinkler query incorporated into Lucene by default, but incorporating it into a query would certainly be better that fetching all stored terms in a custom Similarity.  The default fuzzy query uses the Levenshtein distance, but if that is unacceptable, you could implement your own fuzzy query using the `JaroWinklerDistance` in calculation.  This would certainly help performance, even more so if you could define an acceptable non-fuzzy prefix.

Comment: As far as the penalty against missing words:  The end of a penalty on missing words in the query sounds the same as a bonus for matching words in the query, which is easier to implement, but neither is really the problem here anyway.  I think to penalize missing words in the field could be accomplished with a penalty to longer fields (which would, of course, be wiped out by more matches within those fields).  See `Similarity.computeNorm`, it uses a lengthNorm implementation that should work well in this case, using the length from the `FieldInvertState`.

Comment: I still don't think we have an outline of a solution. I could iterate over the **whole `TermEnum`**, calculating Jaro-Winkler against each term (no prefix can be defined). My current performance is 15 ms and my success rate (the first result is the correct street) is above 90%. This no trifle to keep up with using a different approach. I base my performance on running Jaro-Winkler only against the result set narrowed down by a threshold on Dice's coefficient. BTW field length is not very relevant: each side (query and doc) can contain extra words that simply don't match (they are penalized).

Comment: Why isn't field length relevant?  length - hits = unmatched terms, right?  If two docs have an equal number of hits, the longer doc has more misses.  And iterating over all terms in the field with the distance calculation is exactly what a FuzzyQuery does.  Implementing a JaroWinkler based implementation of the FuzzyQuery seems to make sense.  And the penalty on missed query terms still seems trivial to me.  What's the difference between, on one hand, boosting a matching document, and on the other, penalizing everything else?

Comment: Yes, if I redefined Similarity to use a linear field norm, it could have  make sense in general if I used a linear penalty, but I use a very nonlinear one. A full index scan still doesn't seem the way to go. FuzzyQuery did it like that pre-4.0; now they have the super-smart Levenshtein automaton approach.

Comment: My best idea at the moment is to study the `ValueSource` implementations, there are many more than in 3.6. I may happen to find something of help there.